# Mysterious self transaction erased my funds on Metamask

Tags: ether, metamask, gas, etherscan, gas-price

I wanted to withdraw some ETH from Binance to my Metamask wallet via Ethereum ERC-20 protocol and some "self" transaction erased all of the amount via gas fees. Can you please help me out?
Of course my Metamask balance is zero even after the transaction.

My metamask address is 0x72615EEA90D35BE859853BeFC069716C3256E8db

And here is the transaction itself: [Etherscan transaction](https://etherscan.io/address/0x72615EEA90D35BE859853BeFC069716C3256E8db)

Answer (score 0):

This transaction says, that you sent 0 ETH to your address with pretty high fee rate which was over 2k gwei.

Here is address to actual transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x362d30d76ec2b0a89c2501f7699192baa06665d67c243980f8824202795b847a